# how to use PHP to write the PDF?

Tags: mpdf

It doesn't display ite1 value in the pdf. Why? Could you please, correct my mistake?

```
<?php


set_include_path($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/mpdf/'); 

require('mpdf.php');

$n = 0;
$mpdf=new mPDF();

require_once('../../includes/common.php');
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from sgc where year = '2010'") or die(mysql_error());
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$nric=$row['nric'];
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$meta_ite=$row['meta_ite'];

$mpdf->WriteHTML('<p>Hello World</p>');

$html1 = '<table>
          <tr>
        <td width="388">Module Description</td>
        <td width="111"><div align="center">Grade</div></td>
        <td width="92"><div align="center">Earned</div></td>
        <td width="96"><div align="center">Authority</div></td>
        <td width="74"><div align="center">Series</div></td>
          </tr>';
        $unser = $meta_ite;
      $unser = unserialize($unser);
      $count = count($unser);
      for($j=0;$j<$count;$j++)
      {
          $ite1 = $unser[$i][0];
                //print_r ($unser[$i][0]."--".$unser[$i][1]."--".$unser[$i][2]);

$html1 .= '<tr><td width="388">'.$nric.'</td>
<td width="111">'.$count.'</td>
<td width="92"><div align="center">'.$ite1.'</div></td>
<td width="96">ITE</td>
<td width="74">2010</td>
  </tr>';

      }
 $html1 .= '</table>';

 $mpdf->WriteHTML($html1);
 $mpdf->Output('filename.pdf','D');
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

first you include your **[mpdf](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php)** file

```
require_once('./mpdf/mpdf.php');
```

also open debug functionality to see the error.

```
$mpdf->debug = true;
```

**Note:** ensure that you have complete permission (**777** or **755**) for the following folders on server:

> /ttfontdata/
>   /tmp/
>   /graph_cache/

Comment: NEVER use permission 777... Does he even need executional rights? And for what does the guest need rights? Apart from that: good answer.